# Archive rows to a separate sheet - google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for archiving rows into one tab to another tab based on cell edit within the same spreadsheet. However the size of the sheet is getting very large resulting in slow page load. I was just wondering, as I'm not too experienced in scripts, if it were to possible to "archive" rows into a completely separate google sheet (new URL).

Note: At the moment, if you change Column 6 cell value to "Archive" it sends from one sheet ("Content Production Master") to another sheet ("Content Archive").

See code below for what I've got at the moment - any help would be very useful!

```
  // assumes source data in sheet named Content Production Master
  // target sheet of move to named Content Archive
  // test column with "Archive" is col6
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Content Production Master" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var lastRow = r.getLastRow(); //Save the last edited row index
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var numRows = lastRow-row + 1; // Corrected this calculation
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Content Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    //s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numColumns).moveTo(target); // Take in account the lastRow when archiving the edited range.     
    //s.deleteRow(row);
    for (let i = row; i<=lastRow; i++) {
      s.deleteRow(row);
      console.log(`Deleted row ${row} at pass number ${i}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to move data from your source sheet to a different spreadsheet using [move(target)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget). You can manually get the data to be moved and paste that to another spreadsheet using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Content Production Master" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Archive") {
    //var targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1xh0huhm7ghGP7Y_5jNSFh7eaNX4iVoOL4SY95IWqpfs');
    var targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xh0huhm7ghGP7Y_5jNSFh7eaNX4iVoOL4SY95IWqpfs/edit?resourcekey=0-j6u0gdSEBp-F9SZYlZYi1g#gid=93990300');
    var targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName("Content Archive"); 

    var row = r.getRow();
    var lastRow = r.getLastRow(); //Save the last edited row index
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var numRows = lastRow-row + 1; // Corrected this calculation
    
    //Get data to be moved
    var data = s.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

    //Paste the values to the target sheet on another spreadsheet
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

    //Delete data in the source sheet
    s.deleteRows(row, numRows);
  }
  
}
```

### Pre-requisite(use installable onEdit trigger):

[image]

### What it does?

1. After checking if the modified cell is in column 6 with value "Archive". Open the target spreadsheet using either [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl) or [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid). Then select the target sheet.
2. Get the row values of the range to be moved using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
3. Write the values to your target sheet using [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
4. Delete the archived rows in your source sheet using [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany)

### Output:

**Source Sheet (Before)**

[image]

**Source Sheet (After)**

[image]

**Target Sheet (After)**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly. I did not used an onEdit event object in my sample code.

Comment: Thanks for your help however I've ran the code multiple times (sampled 6 rows all with "archive" in Col6) but it only seemed to work once where it only sent one row across - any ideas?

Comment: As per example provided. Have you selected the all 6 rows with "Archive" in column 6 when running the code? The sample code is based on your original code where it is assumed to be executed as onEdit trigger. By the way, if you put this in an onEdit() don't forget to [create an onEdit installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), it will fail if you only use a simple onEdit trigger since it requires authorization for opening another spreadsheet

Comment: I updated the answer so that you don't need to select the 6 rows with archive before running the code. I tested it and it is working from my side when used as an onEdit installable trigger

Comment: Ah I missed the instructions about highlighting the cells, it works for me now - thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)