# Google Script - creating an archive if one row says "closed"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, archive

I borrowed the code from here: [Archive rows to a separate sheet - google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485206/archive-rows-to-a-separate-sheet-google-sheets)

but basically I am trying to create an automatic archive where the rows of info delete from my master list on the source sheet but ONLY when I change column C to "Closed".

please help

```
Here is my code:


function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('source sheet link');
  //Logger.log(ss.getName());
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Master List" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == "Closed");{
    var targetSs = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('target sheet link');
  //Logger.log(targetSs.getName());
  var targetSheet = targetSs.getSheetByName("Archive");

  var row = r.getRow();
  var lastRow = r.getLastRow(); //save the last edited row index
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var numRows = lastRow-row+2; 
  //Get data to be moved
  var data = s.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numColumns).getValues();

  //Paste the values to the target sheet on another spreadsheet
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);

  //Delete data in the source sheet
  s.deleteRows(row, numRows);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use openByUrl in an onEdit because the onEdit trigger is a simple trigger which does not support processes that require permission.  You can move to an installable trigger if you wish

Comment: @Cooper what should i use instead? like, what is an installable trigger or what could i use instead of "openByUrl"? sorry, ive never used google script before

Comment: [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)